# What are the branches of system ecology?

Tags: ecology, ecosystem

What are the branches of **system ecology** that scientists research in nowadays? Or what can system ecology can applied to, or be used?

I have read its [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systems_ecology) page, but sadly it doesn't answer my question. The most relevant section of it is the "Closely related fields", but again, it doesn't answer my question directly.

**From what I understand**, system ecology is a sub-field of theoretical ecology. It uses thermodynamic in physics to explain a biological system, with the help of network thinking and some technique of visualization. I have presented this in detail [what I understand](http://lyminhnhat.com/2015/09/21/why-i-choose-ecology-to-study-in-grad-school/) on my website.

<sup>Related: [How is the Energy Systems Language used in ecology?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/74192/6786)</sup>

Comment: The new keyword yields more results, but they still aren't satisfied me. Thanks for your compliment, may I see your site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the branches of system ecology that scientists research in nowadays? Or what can system ecology can applied to, or be used?

This field is often referred to as **systems ecology** or ecosystem ecology. It is the study of ecosystems. Thermodynamic principles are often used to construct food/system webs (networks) to understand cause and effect within the system. But I think systems ecology can be considered beyond just a numerical approach to include social (human) dynamics.

A great primer for systems ecology is that by **Howard T. Odum**:

Odum, Howard T. "Systems Ecology; an introduction." (1983).

> I have presented this in detail what I understand on my website.

After reading the post on your website I have some recommendations for complex systems science groups/hubs in which you can look for potential mentors/collaborators/ideas:

1. International Institute for Applied Systems Analysis (IIASA; Austria)
2. Santa Fe Insitute (US)
3. National Socio-Environmental Synthesis Center (SESYNC; US)

Comment: so if the question is "what are the branches of system ecology?", then the answer is "food web with application of thermodynamic is the only branch"? Is that correct?

Comment: I don't know how to answer how many branches there are, since Systems Ecology comprises theories from all over the place. There are groups which focus on ecological interactions only, and those that attempt to incorporate social-ecological interactions.